# Selective Filter rows based on column Value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with a keycolumn and other columns as below.

[image]

Keycolumn is a combination of col1,col2,col3,col4.
For a given key column value I have different values for Col5.
If the key column value has multiple values on Col5 then consider anyone other than 'O'. If all staus are 'O' then consider 'O'.

In the above case I should get 4 rows.Each One from Yellow,Green,Blue and Orange

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon's query has valid idea, but it doesn't follow your rules about picking the non-'O' row if possible.

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        KeyColumn
        ,Col1
        ,Col2
        ,Col3
        ,Col4
        ,Col5
        ,Col6
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY KeyColumn
            ORDER BY 
                CASE WHEN Col5 = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END -- put 'O' last
                ,Col5) as rn -- pick first non-O row
                             -- you can choose other column(s) instead of Col5 here
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT
    KeyColumn
    ,Col1
    ,Col2
    ,Col3
    ,Col4
    ,Col5
    ,Col6
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you would use the ANSI standard `row_number()` function.  Something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by keycolumn order by keycolumn) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t 
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Row number is for a kind of sort. But here it is not the case.